# How to implement NativeProcess in Air app

Tags: actionscript-3, command-line, air

I need to do something very simple with NativeProcess, I need to launch an .exe file via cmd line and pass it one parameter. I have found NativeProcess examples but they are all for far more complex things and are not showing a complete implementation. I have a lot of experience with flash as3 but not in this particular area... if someone could show me how this is accomplished from begining to end I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=125 - this is a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code from Adobe's website for doing exactly what you ask :

```
package
{
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public var process:NativeProcess;

        public function Main()
        {
            if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
                setupAndLaunch();
            else
                trace("NativeProcess not supported.");
        }

        public function setupAndLaunch():void
        {     
            var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
            var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("yourapp.exe");
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

            var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
            processArgs[0] = "the parameter you are passing";
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;

            process = new NativeProcess();
            process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
            process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
            process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData);
            process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
            process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
            process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
        }

        public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            trace("Got: ", process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable)); 
        }

        public function onErrorData(event:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            trace("ERROR -", process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable)); 
        }

        public function onExit(event:NativeProcessExitEvent):void
        {
            trace("Process exited with ", event.exitCode);
        }

        public function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
             trace(event.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And important information `The NativeProcess class and its capabilities are only available to AIR applications installed with a native installer (extended desktop profile applications). When debugging, you can pass the -profile extendedDesktop argument to ADL to enable the NativeProcess functionality. At runtime, you can check the NativeProcess.isSupported property to to determine whether native process communication is supported.`

I tested the above in Flash Develop by setting the application profile to `Extended Desktop` and it works.

More info [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html#includeExamplesSummary).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Baris Usaki's answer two very important points I would like to add are:

1. You must publish the app as .dmg Not as .air. Doing so will put the
   app in /Applications directory.
2. You must set profile only and only to "extended desktop". Also add
       "desktop" if it asks for. Otherwise you will get error:
       "NativeProcess not supported"

I was able to run executable file like /usr/lib/osascript to run .scpt files. However I was not able to run any other .app file located on a folder at desktop. I could not find the reason for that.